# Frame around elements of swatch legend

Tags: legending

I'd like to put a frame around the elements of swatch legend:

```
SwatchLegend[{Red, Green, Blue}, {"label1", "label2", "label3"}, 
 LegendLayout -> "Row"]
```

That is, not around the entire legend like this:

```
SwatchLegend[{Red, Green, Blue}, {"label1", "label2", "label3"}, 
 LegendFunction -> "Frame"]
```

but ONLY around the red, green and blue squares (a separate frame around each square). Is that possible?

Comment: Around all the squares together, or around each square individually?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Around each square separately. Sorry, it didn't became clear I corrected it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One method is to use [`LegendMarkers`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LegendMarkers.html) and draw a frame using an empty [`Rectangle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rectangle.html):

```
SwatchLegend[{Red, Green, Blue}, {"label1", "label2", "label3"}, 
 LegendFunction -> "Frame", LegendMarkerSize -> 30, 
 LegendMarkers -> 
  Graphics[{Rectangle[], FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Opacity[1]], Rectangle[{-1/2, -1/2}, {3/2, 3/2}]}]]
```

[image]

Another is to use [`LegendFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LegendFunction.html) to operate on the contents of the legend, here with [`MapAt`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapAt.html) and a rather unwieldy position specification:

```
SwatchLegend[{Red, Green, Blue}, {"label1", "label2", "label3"}, 
 LegendFunction -> MapAt[Framed, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, All, 1}]]
```

[image]

From a comment below you may want [`EdgeForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EdgeForm.html) rather than a separate frame element:

```
SwatchLegend[{Red, Green, Blue}, {"label1", "label2", "label3"}, 
 LegendFunction -> "Frame", LegendMarkerSize -> 20, 
 LegendMarkers -> Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Thick, Black, Opacity[1]}], Rectangle[]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Ah I see,thank you! So the markers were just replaced by rectangles, interesting solution. Is it possible to remove the space between the colored rectangles and the "frame" rectangle and color the frame Black? I tried: Graphics[{Rectangle[], FaceForm[], Black, 
  Rectangle[{-1/2, -1/2}, {3/2, 3/2}]}] but that didn't seem to work

Comment: @holistic It sounds like you might want `EdgeForm` rather than a separate frame.  I'll add an example of that in a moment.

Comment: Thanks so much for those many examples, could learn a lot :). Yes, EdgeForm works very well, did not know about this yet!